# Build xml document with dart

Tags: xml, dart

I have a situation where i should create an XML document using dart, i checked the [Building method](https://pub.dev/packages/xml#building) described on the XML package documentation, but my case is different, i have to create all elements separately on different methodes including the root element and after that concatenate the nodes, i used to do this in java by using `document.appendChild` and `document.importNode` and conserve the tree hierarchy, does this exist and how i can achieve this using dart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can follow the pattern you describe. In my opinion it is not very efficient to create a document like this, but maybe with some helper methods it becomes easier?

```dart
final document = XmlDocument();
final root = XmlElement(XmlName('root'));
final child = XmlElement(XmlName('child'), [], [XmlText('Hello World!')]);
root.children.add(child);
document.children.add(root);

print(document.toXmlString(pretty: true));
```

The above code prints the following output:

```xml
<root>
  <child>Hello World!</child>
</root>
```

Comment: You are right it's a little bit critical using this pattern but this is the requirement, because i will not just create an XML file but i am about creating a request factory that create Skeleton SOAP Message which depends from many parameters, the end user will use only this Dart package as WS client and set the parameters to consume SOAP WS, this is already made in java and we are migrating to Dart   

https://github.com/ingeint/idempierewsc-java/blob/master/idempierewsc/src/org/idempiere/webservice/client/request/RequestFactory.java  

check createRequest method if u r familiar with java

Comment: doc.children.add(node) do the the job and can use it  like append function, thank you @Lukas Renggli for the package and for the answer